# ConstratintLayout: How to center a view according to another view, vertically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have the following code

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context="gr.teiath.cs.android.tipcalculator.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/AmountLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Amount"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/AmountTV"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Amount"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:digits="0123456789"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:maxLength="10"
        android:maxLines="1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/AmountLabel"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Which results in this

[image]

I do not know if I am describing it correctly but, I want to center the Amount `TextView` according to the Amount `EditText` vertically. Right now, the `TextView` is aligned to the top of the `EditText`. I want to make it like this.

[image]

I added `10dp` of `layout_marginTop` for this, but I don't think it's the way to do it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/AmountLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Amount"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/Amount"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Amount"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:digits="0123456789"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:maxLength="10"
        android:maxLines="1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/AmountLabel"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Give this man a cookie!!! Thanks, worked perfectly. I'm trying to use ConstraintLayout for everything moving forward so I have a lot to learn.

Comment: @KostasAndrianos happy to help you my friend enjoy codding